# Php query to SQL returning foreign characters, only partially correct, why?

Tags: php, mysqli, character-encoding

**The Problem**

I have data on my local computer that is stored in files containing alphabets from around the world (Arabic, chinese, russian, basic latin, etc...) I then used Java to upload all of those files into a mySQL data table.

Now my website uses javascript to get a user's search parameters and sends that to php. Php then queries the SQL table and gets a response. That response is then sent back to JS to be displayed on the webpage.

My problem is currently with the foreign characters of my returned results. I am seeing some of the information correctly, but then some of the foreign characters are being replaced with '?'. Here is an example:

```
This is what I want to see * د افغانستان بانک ۲ دوی افغانی ۱۳۸۳

This is what is being displayed on the webpage * د افغا�?ستا�? با�?ک ۲ د�?�? افغا�?�? ۱۳۸۳
```

You can see that some of the characters are correct, while others have been replaced with the question marks.

I know the data is stored correctly in the SQL table since I can successfully pull down that data using Java. I also know that the issue is not with the Javascript on the web side, since I added a line in my php code to append a fake, additional query result containing the correct characters.

```
$response[] = ' Afghanistan د افغانستان بانک ۲ دوی افغانی ۱۳۸۳';
```

And that is the only "result" that gets displayed correctly on the web page.

Here is what I have tried to do to make this work. Since I have it down to the fact that the data must be getting corrupted from php getting the SQL query results, I have focused on trying to fix that.

```
//mysqli_set_charset($connection, "latin1"); //utf8 || latin1 ||big5 ||cp850 || latin2
```

The comments are all of the versions of encoding that I have tried. The only encoding that has been slightly successful has been the latin1 (default). It is returning the results with the question marks. All the other ones are returning absolute gibberish responses, like:

```
//Ø¯ Ø§ÙØºØ§ÙØ³ØªØ§Ù Ø¨Ø§ÙÚ© Û² Ø¯ÙÛ Ø§ÙØºØ§ÙÛ Û±Û³Û¸Û³
//which should be: د افغانستان بانک ۲ دوی افغانی ۱۳۸۳
```

From the same php script I have also uploaded foreign characters using a php SQL "INSERT INTO" statement. And I am able to successfully pull down those complete characters when accessing the table with Java.

**The Question**

How can I get this php code to return the correct results?

I am so lost as to what is wrong, if you guys have any knowledge on this I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you so much!

Comment: Is there any HTTP communication involved? If so, debug data sent back and forth in request/response pairs to see if it's still correct when sent/received, HTTP encoding may be one possible problem. Also, browser encoding worth checking.

Answer (score 0):

Use utf-8 both in php as well as in MySQL. You can convert the php string encoding using...

```
 $str = mb_convert_encoding($response, "UTF-8");
```

In mysql either make the whole table charset as "utf-general-*" or just the column. And just after establishing the connection, set the transfer encoding using the following SQL

```
 SET NAMES utf8
```

It is important to be consistent everywhere.